# Combining 2 mysql instances into 1 without downtime

Tags: mysql

Can I use replication from one database server to another and then start using instance for production and then import other database server into new instance and then use replication to catch up and then use the new database server that contains both database servers combined into 1

Comment: "Import" takes time; "catchup" takes time.  Please elaborate on why you need to combine two versions.  Your answer may point us in a direction to best help you.

Comment: I am looking to take 2 rds instances and combine to 1 without downtime by using replication twice

Comment: While you are importing, you probably can't allow writes to the 'source'.  Won't this be "downtime"?

Comment: I am not sure if I get what do you want exactly but if you are looking for database sync you can test workbench https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-database-synchronization.html

Comment: @rick James I would write to source even during import then on my new source use replication to catch up. Then failover for one database cluster to new master then repeat process for other server